# JRebel: how to disable hbm2dll schema export in JRebel?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jrebel

The question says it all. i'm using jrebel (5.5)

for hibernate plugin it says: "Enables automatic schema updating if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update or schemaUpdate=true on org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean."

how can i disable it (or change)? it deletes and recreates (incorrect) my database schema on every start/stop and clean...

thx

Answer (score 1):

Pardon,
i've found out that my full text search failed badly.
there was another setting for this in the persistence.xml. feeling dumb right now.

```
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

change it to:

```
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
```

did it for me